# Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect to kafka from spark streaming with the following code to do a small POC.

This is how i started Kafka

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties

bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties 

bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test

bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test

bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

here is my Spark streaming code for receiving the messages and printing them on the console.

```
object ReadingFromKafkaSource extends App {

  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)


  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .setAppName("test")

  val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(20))


  val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(streamingContext, "localhost:9092", "spark-streaming-configuration-group", Map("test" -> 1))

  lines.print()

  streamingContext.start()

  streamingContext.awaitTermination()

}
```

I am getting the following error message.

```
4:45:26.002 [RecurringTimer - BlockGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer - Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1520952326000
14:45:26.204 [RecurringTimer - BlockGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer - Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1520952326200
14:45:26.405 [RecurringTimer - BlockGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer - Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1520952326400
14:45:26.601 [RecurringTimer - BlockGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer - Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1520952326600
14:45:26.801 [RecurringTimer - BlockGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer - Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1520952326800
14:45:27.000 [RecurringTimer - BlockGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer - Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1520952327000
14:45:27.201 [RecurringTimer - BlockGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer - Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1520952327200
14:45:27.244 [Executor task launch worker for task 99] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Closing session: 0x0
14:45:27.244 [Executor task launch worker for task 99] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Closing client for session: 0x0
14:45:27.401 [RecurringTimer - BlockGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer - Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1520952327400
14:45:27.600 [RecurringTimer - BlockGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer - Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1520952327600
14:45:27.742 [Executor task launch worker for task 99-SendThread(localhost:9092)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x0 : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 3005ms for sessionid 0x0
14:45:27.801 [RecurringTimer - BlockGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer - Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1520952327800
14:45:27.844 [Executor task launch worker for task 99] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Disconnecting client for session: 0x0
14:45:27.844 [Executor task launch worker for task 99] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x0 closed
14:45:27.844 [Executor task launch worker for task 99-EventThread] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
14:45:27.844 [Executor task launch worker for task 99] INFO org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl - Stopping receiver with message: Error starting receiver 0: org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
14:45:27.844 [Executor task launch worker for task 99] INFO org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl - Called receiver onStop
14:45:27.844 [Executor task launch worker for task 99] INFO org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl - Deregistering receiver 0
14:45:27.845 [dispatcher-event-loop-1] ERROR org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker - Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Error starting receiver 0 - org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1232)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:156)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:130)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:75)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:57)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:191)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:139)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:156)
    at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:607)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:597)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2173)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2173)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Kafka works fine, but spark streaming says that there is an issue with connecting to zookeeper service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided the port of Kafka broker, you should provide the port of Zookeeper instead (as you can see in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html)), which is actually 2181 by default, try using `localhost:2181` instead of `localhost:9092`. That should resolve the problem for sure (assuming you have Kafka and Zookeper running).

Comment: I followed this solution but I got another problem. The consummer cannot print out the messages from the producer

Answer (score 1):

I'd the same error.  I resolved it by changing the port number 9092 to 2181(from zoo.cfg - property clientPort=2181)